# How to add a property to reactive object VueJS 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const imageUrl = ref("");
    const title = ref("");
    const description = ref("");
    var source = "Global";

    const form = reactive({
      title: "",
      description: "",
      // src: source,
    });
    //...
  }
}
```

How do I add `src: "source"` (a new property) to `form` (the reactive object)? Like how we append on ref.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the field directly via `form.src = source`. For example, you could have a function that does this:

```js
const addSourceToForm = () => form.src = source
```

And you can call that function later, e.g., from a button click:

```html
<button @click="addSourceToForm">Add source</button>
```

[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72417023/6277151)